# importing Schema from '@nestjs/mongoose' vs importing it from 'mongoose'

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

Can anyone explain the difference between these 2 imports ?

```js
import { Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
```

&

```js
import { Schema as mongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';
```

Answer (score 1):

`import { Schema } from '@nestjs/mongoose'`

imports the `Schema` [class decorator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators)

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection

While

`import { Schema as mongooseSchema } from 'mongoose'`

is to import the `Schema` *class* (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#schemas) and rename it to `mongooseSchema` (to avoid name clashes, I guess)